# Synonym für "Ich bin ein Bayern/Hertha/...-Fan"

Tags: synonym

Eine Google-Suche nach "Ich stehe auf Bayern" ergibt nur zwei Treffer. "Ich bin ein Bayern-Anhänger" ist es auch nicht.

Wie kann ich dann noch "Ich bin ein Bayern-Fan" sagen?

Comment: "Ich bin Bayern-Anhänger" *ist* ein Synonym. Was stört Dich daran?

Comment: @Uwe Ich hatte gesucht nur nach "Ich bin **ein** Bayern-Anhänger". Das ergit kein Treffer. Danke

Comment: *Mein* Google liefert mir für "Bayern-Anhänger" seitenweise Ergebnisse. Ein Großteil davon bezieht sich auf Fussballfans.

Comment: "Ich bin (ein) Bayern-Fan/Bayern-Anhänger" geht sowohl mit als auch ohne Artikel; die Formen ohne Artikel sind wahrscheinlich etwas  gebräuchlicher.

Comment: Wie wär's denn, einfach das Internet zu befragen: Google liefert z.B.: synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/fan.php

Comment: @äüö I suchte nicht ein Synonym für `fan`, aber für den ganzen Satz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Fan](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Fan)

Ist ein eingedeutsches Fremdwort aus dem US-Amerikanischen, ürsprünglich entlehnt über das Französische aus dem lateinischen `fanaticus`, von dem auch das deutsche Fremdwort *[fanatisch](https://www.dwds.de/wb/fanatisch)* entlehnt ist. Genaus die überschwängliche Leidenschaft in der Bedeutung von *fanatisch* spiegelt auch die Bedeutung von ***Fan***:

> jmd., der für etw. überschwänglich begeistert ist, besonders für Sport und Jazz <sup>[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Fan)</sup>
>   begeisterter Anhänger, begeisterte Anhängerin von jemandem, etwas <sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fan)</sup>

Eben diese Mitbedeutung können deutsche Alternativen nicht bieten. Wohl auch deshalb hat sich *Fan* als eingedeutschtes Lehnwort seit der Mitte des 20. Jahrhunderts so durchgesetzt:

> - Marga hatte offensichtlich gemerkt, daß er kein Fan war, und setzte ihre Erläuterungen fort. <sup>Martin Walser, Ehen in Phillipsburg, 1957</sup>
> - Der Referent bittet die applaudierenden Fans um Verzeihung; <sup>Der Tagesspiegel, 1963</sup>
> - Ist der Trainer, fragten die Fans, ein alternder Kanzler? <sup>Die Zeit, 1962</sup>

Es gibt also kein 100% gleichbedeutendes deutsches Analogwort für *Fan*, zumindest nicht im Kontext von Sport oder Musik.

Das wird besonders deutlich, wenn man die diversen Komposita anschaut, bei denen der *Fan* nicht ausgetauscht werden kann (*Fanartikel, Fanmeile, Fanblock, Fanklub, Fanpost* etc.).

Comment: Für Fußballfans ist [Name des Vereins einsetzen]-Anhänger mMn ein perfektes Synonym.